# Play framework 2.2.1 deleting record through ajax, method: delete

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

After reading play 2.2.1 documentation as i can see there is no built-in mechanism for handling HTTP delete method? (nor PUT?) When i say built-in i mean on, for example, rails have `method="delete"` which can be used with `<a></a>` to invoke action by DELETE verb.
 So for example on following picture i have a list of users(GET /users ...).
[image]

How i understand i can simulate delete method through AJAX call, so i tried on following way:

// index.scala.html

```
@users.map { user =>
...
<td> <a href="#" class="delete-user" data-id="@user.getId()"> Delete </td>
...
}
```

// script.js

```
$(function() {
    $('.delete-user').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var $that = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: jsRoutes.controllers.Users.delete(id).url,
            type: "DELETE"
        }).done(function() {
            $that.closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

// Users.java (controller)

```
@Transactional
public static Result delete(Long id) {
    JPA.em().remove(JPA.em().find(User.class, id));
    return ok("User with id=" + id + " has been deleted");
}
```

**So is this proper way to do this? or i misunderstand/overlooked documentation?**

Comment: Rails doesn't really support `PUT` and `DELETE` in the way you're understanding. Rather, it uses `POST` and simulates the other methods with a hidden field. So yes, you're on the right track.

Comment: I was talking in context of support from framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing exactly the right way to do it.  I might just mention one small improvement, you should be able to do this:

```
$.ajax(
  jsRoutes.controllers.Users.delete(id)
).done(function() {
  $that.closest('tr').remove();
});
```

The JavaScript router conveniently returns an object that contains the `url` property that you're already reading, but it also contains a `type` property, which if your route is configured to be a `DELETE` route, will have a value of `DELETE`.  In my applications I will often write a helper method that allows me to easily add other properties to the jQuery AJAX request call too, eg:

```
function ajax(route, params) {
  return $.ajax($.extend(params, route))
}
```

Then I can do things like this:

```
ajax(jsRoutes.controllers.Users.delete(id), {
  headers: { "Auth-Token": "foobar" }
}).done( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the routing object directly to make the call, e.g.

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Users.delete(id).ajax( {
  done: function ( data ) {
    $that.closest('tr').remove();
  }
});
```